# master detail in ionic using json data

Tags: angularjs, json, mobile, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic v1 and trying to create list and its own detail, but when I click on the item list the detail view doesn't display the data of the item selected.

**Factory**

```
.factory('Eventos', function($http){ 

var eventos = [];  

return {
    all : function() {
        return $http.get("eventos.json").then(function(response) {
            eventos = response;
            return eventos;
        }); 
    },
    get : function(eventoId) {     
        for(i = 0; i < eventos.length; i++) {
            if(eventos[i].id === eventoId){
                return eventos[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    } 
}});
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('EventosCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Eventos) { 

    Eventos.all().then(function(eventos) {
        $scope.eventos = eventos.data; 
    });  
})

.controller('EventoCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Eventos) { 

    $scope.evento = Eventos.get($stateParams.eventoId);
}
```

But if I use the data static in the code this works, but I don't know whats wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running a webserver of any kind and just testing with file://index.html, then you're probably running into same-origin policy issues.

Many browsers don't allow locally hosted files to access other locally hosted files.

Try referencing your data as an object

```
var obj = {list:null};

$http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
    // you can do some processing here
    obj.list = data;
});    

return obj;
```

Comment: still the same, only when I display the list its ok, but not display the detail content when I click an item

Comment: could you update your question with some error logs or something that will help diagnose the problem. Fire up your browser console and see what is happening when you click on a list..

Comment: I solved! adding the defer and $q thanks for your help